# How to create Web pages with paragraphs and images in sharepoint using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

i'm trying to create a webpage in my sharepoint site. Can someone please help me to create webpage containing paragraph and images using REST APIs.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Do you need modern or classic pages? SharePoint  REST is not capable of adding Webparts to Pages. What platform are you using to call REST? SPFx webparts? script webpart? console app?

Comment: Hi @Denis I'm using Sharepoint 2016. I need modern pages. I'm calling the REST APIs in Postman.

Comment: There are no modern pages in SP 2016. REST won't let you add webparts to pages. But you can use SSOM, CSOM, JSOM, PowerShell PnP